# Laravel submit button does not go to the next page and previous page

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form page . When a user fills up all the input fields, then the form page goes to the preview page with the data. Preview page has 2 buttons. One is back and the other is next. If the user presses the back 
 button, then user can edit his/her information. If the user press the next, the the data is stored in the database before going to the done page. But in the preview, the back and next button do not go the next or previous pages.

This is the first form page:
[image: this is the first form page]

This is the 2nd preview page after submit the first page:
[image: this is the 2nd preview page after submit the first page]

This is after click the next or back button in preview:
[image: this is after click the next or back button in preview]

This is the controller

```
    public function preview(PERequest $request) {

        $pE = new PE($request->all());
        $cIs = $request->c;

        return view('kakaku.package_estimates.preview', compact('pE', 'cIs'));

    }
   public function done(PERequest $request)
    {
        $input= $request->except('action');
         if ($request->action === 'back') {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($input);
         }
         $pE = new PE();
         $pE->fill($request->all())->save();
         $pEC = [];
         foreach ($request->c as $cI) {
            $pEC = [
               'p' => $pE->id,
               'c' => $cI
            ];
           $pE->pEC()->createMany([$pEC]);
        }

        return view('k.p_e.done');

    }
```

This is the route

```
Route::post('p/preview','K\Controller@preview')->name('k.p.preview');
Route::post('ps/done','K\Controller@done')->name('k.p.done');
```

This are the preview page submit buttons

```
{!! Form::submit('abc',['name' => 'server_back_button','class'=>'btn reediting_btn']) !!}
{!! Form::submit ('acb',['name'=>'commit','class'=>'btn estimate_done_btn_top','data-disable-with'=>'bcd']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think you need to return a view after POST request, you need to redirect user to existing view. Something like this:

```
 public function preview(PERequest $request) {

    $pE = new PE($request->all());
    $cIs = $request->c;

    return redirect('your-kakaku-route')->withSuccess('Some success message');

}
```

As you may guessed **your-kakaku-route** is the url of your view.